# Blazorise fluentvalidation in datagrid Net 8.0

Tags: blazor, fluentvalidation, fluent, .net-8.0, blazorise

I'm trying to implement fluent validation in blazorise datagrid.

Steps:

```
 services
      .AddBlazorise();
 services
     .AddBootstrapProviders()
     .AddFontAwesomeIcons()
 .AddBlazoriseFluentValidation();`
```

Markup for datagrid

```
<DataGrid TItem="ProductBrandVM" class="table table-responsive-lg table-bordered table-striped table-sm mb-0 Dtable"
     Data="@productbrandsResult.Data"
     @bind-SelectedRow="@selectedProductBrand"
     Editable
     Responsive
     UseValidation
     ShowPager
     CommandMode="DataGridCommandMode.ButtonRow"
     RowUpdated="@OnRowUpdatedAsync"
     RowInserted="@OnRowInsertedAsync"
     Filterable FilterMode="DataGridFilterMode.Menu"
     EditMode="editMode">
    <DataGridColumns>
        <DataGridColumn Field="@nameof(ProductBrandVM.ProductBrandCode)" Caption="Code" Editable />
        <DataGridColumn Field="@nameof(ProductBrandVM.ProductBrandName)" Caption="Name" Editable />
     
        <DataGridCommandColumn NewCommandAllowed="false" EditCommandAllowed="false" DeleteCommandAllowed="false" CancelCommandAllowed>
           <SaveCommandTemplate>
               <Button ElementId="btnSave" Type="ButtonType.Submit" Color="Color.Primary" Clicked="@context.Clicked">@context.LocalizationString</Button>
               </SaveCommandTemplate>
               <CancelCommandTemplate>
                   <Button ElementId="btnCancel" Color="Color.Secondary" Clicked="@context.Clicked">@context.LocalizationString</Button>
               </CancelCommandTemplate>
           </DataGridCommandColumn>
       </DataGridColumns>
       <ButtonRowTemplate>
           <Button Color="Color.Success" Clicked="context.NewCommand.Clicked">New</Button>
           <Button Color="Color.Primary" Disabled="(selectedProductBrand is null)" Clicked="context.EditCommand.Clicked">Edit</Button>
           <Button Color="Color.Danger" Disabled="(selectedProductBrand is null)" Clicked="context.DeleteCommand.Clicked">Delete</Button>
           <Button Color="Color.Link" Clicked="context.ClearFilterCommand.Clicked">Clear Filter</Button>
       </ButtonRowTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Code:

```
 public void CheckName(ValidatorEventArgs validationArgs)
 {
     ValidationRule.IsNotEmpty(validationArgs);

     if (validationArgs.Status == ValidationStatus.Error)
     {
         validationArgs.ErrorText = "Name can't be empty.";
     }
 }

<DataGridColumn Field="@nameof(ProductBrandVM.ProductBrandName)" 
     Validator="@CheckName" Caption="Name" Editable />
```

When I try to create a record with empty fields the popup window closes automatically.